# What is causing this unusual cull and how can I fix it?

Tags: python, opengl

I am an extreme novice to OpenGL, just trying to hack something together for a personal project.  When I enabled GL_CULL_FACE I mostly got what I wanted, except a big triangle chunk is now missing from my cube!

[image: Why is it missing a triangle!?]

What might be happening here and how can I fix it?  I made this cube with 6 GL_QUADS, so I never expected to be missing a triangle like this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each polygon has a "front" and "back" side, and when culling is on you only see polygons whose "front" is toward you (the ones for which the normal is pointing toward the camera).

The fact that this face is getting culled from this angle suggests that its normal points inside the cube instead of outside; to flip it around, reverse the order in which you specify the vertices.

Comment: *"this angle suggests that its normal points inside the cube"* - OpenGL [Face Culling](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Face_Culling) depends on the winding order of the primitives (not on the face normal)

Comment: I thought the winding order *was* what defined the normal, but it's been about 20 years since I took graphics in school so it's all extremely fuzzy :P